# Error al convertir html a PDF con Weasyyprint

Tags: python, pandas, pdf

Estoy intentando convertir una tabla de Excel a PDF. Para ello, le doy formato HTML y lo convierto a PDF con Weaseyprint. Hasta hace unas semanas funcionaba perfectamente, pero desde hace unos días me da este error relacionado con pango:

```
AttributeError: function/symbol 'pango_context_set_round_glyph_positions' not found in library 'libpango-1.0.so.0': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: pango_context_set_round_glyph_positions
```

Os dejo el trozo de código donde hago la conversión:

```
out_pdf= 'demo_propuesta.pdf'

weasyprint.HTML(intermediate_html).write_pdf(out_pdf)
```

He intentado, como dicen en el foro de GitHub de la librería, hacer el downgrade a Weasyprint 52.0, pero no funciona aún así. Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo funcionar o instalar la versión correcta de pango?